# Failing in WebScraping products names PUPPETEER JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

So this is my code right now

My goal is to WebScrape and print in console the first 10 products names in https://www.nike.com.br/Snkrs#estoque

However, it's returning the same name 10 times

```
"Kybrid S2Pineapple Comprar

Kybrid S2Pineapple Comprar

...

Kybrid S2Pineapple Comprar"
```

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const { stringify } = require('querystring');
    
    async function Teste(){
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false
        })
        page = await browser.newPage();
        
        await page.goto('https://www.nike.com.br/Snkrs#estoque');
    
        await page.waitForSelector('#DadosPaginacaoEstoque');
    
        var s = 10
        var i = 1
        
        while (i != s){
            w = await page.evaluate('document.querySelector("#DadosPaginacaoEstoque > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child("+String(i)+") > div > div.produto__detalhe").innerText');
            console.log(w);
            i = i + 1;
        }
        console.log(s)
    }
    Teste();
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Ah I think the page.$$eval function will get you where you need to be.

The reason it’s printing the same value over and over is because your query is returning the same value over and over.   You should use page.$$eval to use queryselectorall and abandon your while loop altogether so it'd be something like this

```js
 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
 const { stringify } = require('querystring');   
 
async function Teste(){
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
     headless: false
   })
   page = await browser.newPage();  
   await page.goto('https://www.nike.com.br/Snkrs#estoque');   
   await page.waitForSelector('#DadosPaginacaoEstoque');
   // from what I've seen this works
   let selector = "#DadosPaginacaoEstoque div.produto__detalhe"
   let products = await page.$$eval(selector, lists=>lists.map(items=>items.innerText))
   console.log(products.splice(0,10))
 }
    Teste();
```

Comment: It's returning an error saying that "#DadosPaginacaoEstoque > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child > div > div.produto__detalhe" is not a valid selector. And could you explain the difference in page.$$eval and page.evaluate functions?

Comment: It's probably because it's missing a number after the second div:nth-child("number is supposed to be here")

Comment: Ah im sorry i've never used `nth-child` prop. Depending on the number of divs that use the produto__detalhe classname you may be able to just use `"#DadosPaginacaoEstoque div.produto__detalhe"` as your selector

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just have a small typo with quotes. Try this:

```js
w = await page.evaluate('document.querySelector("#DadosPaginacaoEstoque > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(' + String(i) + ') > div > div.produto__detalhe").innerText');
```